# Gradle subprojects dependency on shared code

Tags: java, scala, gradle, dependencies

Suppose, I have this in settings.gradle: `include 'a', 'b', 'c', 'shared'`

Naturally, I want a, b, and c all depend on 'shared', so I put this into gradle.build: `subprojects { dependencies { project(":shared") }}`

This does not work however: trying to compile it fails, because of a circular dependency ('shared' depends on itself).

Is there any way around this, other that having to list the dependency explicitly for every subproject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a condition based on project name.

```
subprojects { 
    if (!project.name.contains('shared')) dependencies { compile project(":shared") }
}
```

(Haven't tested, but some form of this should work)

Comment: As a note, project.name doesn't contain a `:`. So, the name should be just `shared`

Comment: Thanks. I actually found a different but similar way: `configure(subprojects - project(':shared')) { dependencies { ... } }` This works too.